# UIPopover preventing shake to undo

Tags: ipad, ios5, uipopovercontroller, nsundomanager, uipopover

I have an app which allows text input in various situations. When the text is input into a UITextView or UITextField inside a UIPopover, shake to undo does not work. The UIAlertView asking if you want to undo does not appear when the device (or the simulator) is shaken.

Where I have UITextFields which are not contained in UIPopovers, shake to undo works as expected.

What could be preventing shake to undo from working when the text input field is within a UIPopover?

My deployment target is iOS 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem, however I am starting to think that this is intentional as I am also unable to undo typing in popovers in Apples on apps (e.g. Safari and Maps).

Maybe the idea is, that you don't need an undo action there as tapping anywhere outside the popover dismisses the popover without saving.